# What is the purpose of types which may be replaced by others?

Tags: data-types, numbers

In Kotlin or Java we have many different types: integer, byte, double, long, float, string, character, etc.

But one can use an integer instead of byte, and a double instead of an integer.

Why we need all those different type? Why we can't just have a double, and forget about integer, byte, float, etc.?

Comment: This is a good question, though some people here will likely downvote it, because the post does not show any research effort, and the tags were not well chosen (I fixed this for you). In early Basic dialects, the only internally used number data type was indeed a "float", by design. In [RISC CPUs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_Instruction_Set_Computer), the number of data types were intentionally reduced compared to former CISC CPU architectures.

Comment: OK thanks you for your editing

Comment: Think about a workshop with tools. You can get by with fewer tools but it is not going to make your life easier. If you have pliers you don't really need a hammer, right? Just bang in those nails with the flat side of your pliers. Same with screw drivers, screw them! Just grab the head of the screw with your pliers and twist away. It is all backwards though, literally, since we typically build more powerful things from simple things, particularly in computing. Because it makes the work quicker, safer and easier.

Comment: Try doing math in JavaScript. Any math, really. And then you will see why we have different numeric types. Oh, the pain...

Comment: A 64 bit `double` cannot hold all 64 bit `long long` values with the same accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

Under the hood, everything is an array of bytes, so why do *you* need anything else?

Different types make the code simpler and make it easier to reason about the code. They avoid errors. They save memory. They document the interface. Here's a method: `resetCounter(double value)`. Tell me, are values 23,768 and 0.5 valid as arguments? Or will the method crash? Now what if the signature is rather `resetCounter(short value)`?

Imagine you have a stream of bytes (a binary file, for instance). Your suggestion is to forget about bytes, and use doubles instead. Well...

- Double is 64 bits long, versus 8 bits for a byte. This means that your stream will be eight times bigger, for no benefit whatsoever. Imagine that you need to download eight gigabytes in order to get your one gigabyte file. Why would you want to do such a thing?
- Something, somewhere, may assign a value such as 7,502 to a the byte (that you decided to replace by a double). What would happen when you try to compress the stream? Or pass show it as an image on the screen? What if the value is 7,502.3333333333?
- Do you think somebody who will maintain the source code will know, automatically, that all the values should be within the -128..127 range, or that one shouldn't do floating point operations on them? How?
- At some point, you need to verify that the stream starts by 0xC49F02. Write the code which would do that. How easy/difficult it is, compared to the similar code for the stream of bytes? How confident are you that the code is correct? How many tests did you write? What tests are here just because you used double instead of a byte?

Comment: Okey, thank you so much